# Have a trouble in Laravel+Nginx+MariaDB docker-containers from nginx config

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, configuration

I have a docker-compose from this nginx, php and MariaDB containers, but when I put into nginx.conf http{} block, he sad, that it's incorrect, but it's from internet examples.

```
docker-compose file
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./_docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    container_name: beach_nginx
  
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: dancher
        uid: 1000
        gid: 1000
      context: .
      dockerfile: _docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - '8082:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: beach_appx

  
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.10
    
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: beach_db
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    
    ports:
      - 8101:3306
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

It's config in nginx.conf file. Http can't place in this line, he sad. Also user nginx can't place here too. My config work if I delete all and save server{ location /}.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;
worker_cpu_affinity auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
pcre_jit on;

events {
    worker_connections 8192;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    # Basic #######################
    
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    keepalive_timeout 120;
    keepalive_requests      1000;
    types_hash_max_size     2048;
    server_tokens       off;
    send_timeout        30;
    client_body_timeout     30;
    client_header_timeout   30;
    server_names_hash_max_size  4096;

    # Limits ######################
    
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_body_temp_path   /var/cache/nginx/client_temp;

    proxy_connect_timeout   60;
    proxy_send_timeout      60;
    proxy_read_timeout      60;
    proxy_buffer_size       4k;
    proxy_buffers       8 16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size  64k;
    proxy_temp_path     /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
 
    # Logs ########################

    m_header_time';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Gzip ########################

    gzip on; 
    gzip_static on; 
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;

    etag off;
    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # For monitoring ###########
    
    server {

    index index.html index.php;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    client_max_body_size 50m;
    
    location / {
        #Basic

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        reset_timedout_connection on;
        #keepalive_timeout 120;
        keepalive_requests 1000;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;
        send_timeout 30;
        client_body_timeout 30;
        #client_header_timeout 30;
        #server_names_hash_max_size 4096;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        limit_req zone=one;
        # kill cache
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
}`
```

I tried put http{} block in different places, but it's not working.

Comment: Why do you think it's incorrect?  What's not working?  What URL are you trying to request, from what context, and with what result?

Comment: Container cant't start from this config file

Comment: I saw in the logs that nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here